# Setting UberCart stock levels on content creation?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

Currently if you create a product in UberCart, you have to first create the product before accessing the stock tab to set stock levels. I want to be able to set the stock levels when I create the product. I.e. Right below where I set the "list price". How would I do this?

Comment: Whats wrong here? It has to exist before it can be given additional attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's going to involve a little work.

1. You're going to have to create a hook_form_alter implementation to add the new form fields to the node_add/node_edit form.
2. You're going to want to add a hook_nodeapi() implementation for $op=='validate' to make sure you're getting valid information.
3. You're then going to want to extend that hook_nodeapi() implementation for $op=='insert' and 'update' to grab the field value (which should be stuck to the $node object) and write it to the stock levels table, whose name I'm too lazy to look up right now.

Alternately, instead of 2 and 3, you could mess around with creating a validation and submit function, and append them to the #validate and #submit arrays of the form.

Comment: I was hoping for a "download module abc to get it done" answer. :-p Okay... will get cracking.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for a module-based solution to this problem in Drupal 7, the latest dev version of the "Ubercart Product Power Tools" module has an excellent per-product setting to make stock-tracking active on creation, as well as set default stock quantity and threshold for the product.

- [Ubercart Product Power Tools](https://drupal.org/project/uc_product_power_tools)